# Change a value of "AutoCompleteTextView" in one Activity from another Class

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, browser

Here I have one Activity TabActivity which has a layout resource file and contains a AutoCompleteTextView with id **address_bar**

I am trying to change the value of the AutoCompleteTextView from another class file WebViewClient. How can I achieve it

**TabActivity** code:

```
    class TabActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    ...................
    
        address.setText(WebChromeClient.abc.get())
            var address: AutoCompleteTextView? = null
            address = findViewById<View>(R.id.address_bar) as AutoCompleteTextView
    ...................
    }
```

**WebViewClient** code:

```
class WebViewClient : android.webkit.WebViewClient() {
..................


..................
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Please correct me if I'm wrong, you want to change the value of `AutoCompleteText` in the `WebViewClient` class, and when you bring back to `TabActivity`, the `AutoCompleteText `value must be changed

Comment: The AutoCompleteTextView is in TabActivity, and WebViewClient is a class file. WebViewClient is called by WebView (inside frameLayout) that is inside TabActivity

Comment: you have to use interface for this, or local broadcast manager

Comment: Can you please provide me a example code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the code snippet in WebViewClient Class solved my issue:

```
val address: AutoCompleteTextView = (activity as TabActivity).address_bar
```